# why class of main method should be public in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

here is a template code of netbeans IDE for a JavaFX project.
if you clear public keyword from BombDroid class you get runtime error.why?
Note:I know that main should be public.But why Bombdroid class should be public?

```
package bombdroid;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BombDroid extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        Line line = new Line(0, 0, 500, 500);
        Rectangle man = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
        root.getChildren().add(line);
        root.getChildren().add(man);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
        }
    }
```

Comment: My guess would be that because it's different classes that end up calling `main`, those classes cannot see that class, because it's `default` or `package-private`. I'd be interested to see what happens if you set the package to the same as the calling code (`java.lang` maybe?)

Comment: @Zymus, this is an application launched by the JRE runtime launcher `java`.  There is no user code which acts as calling code.  All calling code is in the JRE.  Due to JRE security restrictions user code cannot be placed in java.lang (`java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.lang`), so it is not possible to try the test you suggest.

Comment: While it may be tempting to think this question is a duplicate of the related question: [why main method in Java need to be public always?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20776413/why-main-method-in-java-need-to-be-public-always), it is not as this question refers to the access classifier on the class containing the main method, not the main method itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The launcher for JavaFX applications works via reflection, a consequence of which and the way it is used is that a JavaFX Application class must be declared public.

The specific error message you get when running your sample (without a main method, which is unnecessary for a JavaFX application) is:

```
Exception in Application constructor
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class BombDroid
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:907)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: BombDroid.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:818)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
```

As you can see, the system is looking for a no-argument constructor to your application class.  Tracing through, the source code at `LauncherImpl.java:818`, is:

```
Constructor<? extends Application> c = appClass.getConstructor();
```

The documentation for the `getConstructor()` method states:

> Returns a `Constructor` object that reflects the specified public constructor of the class represented by this `Class` object.
>
> @throws NoSuchMethodException if a matching method is not found.

If your application class is not public, it has no public constructor, and a NoSuchMethodException is returned when you try to launch it.  Which is what is happening here, causing the launch of the Application to fail.

*Aside*

Note the requirement that the Application class for JavaFX be public differs from a non-JavaFX application.  For example, the simplest hello world program in Java does not require a public class to run, only a public main method.

```
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello, world");
    }
}
```