# JavaFX access error, not sure what's causing it

Tags: java, javafx, graphics

This is my code (I removed a lot of graphics logic as to see if it would run a most basic file)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

class Client extends Application {
    public static String host = "127.0.0.1";
    public BufferedReader fromServer;
    public PrintWriter toServer;
    public Scanner consoleInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    public Client() {
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage displayStage) {     
        try {
            System.out.println("HELLO");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Client connection error!"); 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

but the error messages are really bizarre and I'm not sure what exactly it means; it mentions a public access but afaik, public means anything can access it and I don't use reflection but its throwing errors regarding reflection and I'm really stumpted as to what could be causing this error.

```
Exception in Application constructor
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class eHillsClient.Client
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:891)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl (in module javafx.graphics) cannot access a member of class eHillsClient.Client with modifiers "public"
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:392)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:674)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:489)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:803)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: Application is started via reflection, so any errors in startup are wrapped into an InvocationException. The real error is that it must be public (yours is package private)

Comment: What would I have to do fix this issue?

Comment: Your `Application` subclass has to be public.

Answer (score 0):

Make Client class `public` because a main class in `JavaFX Applicaions` must have a public access modifier to be picked by `getConstructor()` method in `Application` class.In normal cases it wouldn't cause an error but your main class will not be an entry point to the program(in `JavaFx Applicaions` the entry points is `Applicaion` class).

You can further read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36293375/why-class-of-main-method-should-be-public-in-javafx#:%7E:text=The%20launcher%20for%20JavaFX%20applications,class%20must%20be%20declared%20public.&text=As%20you%20can%20see%2C%20the,constructor%20to%20your%20application%20class.)

Comment: Does Client not automatically default to public if no access identifier is given?

Comment: No you must explicitly add public access modifier.

Comment: @ArronStarmer looks like time to work through a tutorial on java language basics :)

Comment: Ah thanks. My memory has not served me well (for the default mode which this is the first time I've dealt with it)

Comment: The explanation in this is not really correct. The JavaFX launcher (invoked by `Application.launch()`) uses reflection to create an instance of the `Application` subclass, and for *that* reason the class must be `public`. It has nothing to do with being an entry point: the `main(…)` method is invoked without problem. I don’t know why you are referring to “compilation errors”: there are no compilation errors here.